# NoMethodError in Controller#like

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

I can't for the life of me figure out this error.

[image]

```
NoMethodError in ValuationsController#like 
undefined method `valuation_likes` for #<User:0x007fb3b21b9fc8>
#LINE IN VALUATIONS_CONTROLLER: @valuation_like = current_user.valuation_likes.build(valuation: @valuation)
```

The purpose of the code is so that user's can **like** other user's values (aka `:valuations`).

**valuations_controller**

```
  def like
    @valuation = Valuation.find(params[:id])
    @valuation_like = current_user.valuation_likes.build(valuation: @valuation)
    if @valuation_like.save
      @valuation.increment!(:likes)
      flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Two many likes'
    end  
      redirect_to(:back)
  end
```

**valuation_like.rb**

```
class ValuationLike < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :valuation
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: :valuation }
  belongs_to :liker, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

**valuation.rb**

```
  has_many :valuation_likes 
  has_many :likers, through: :valuation_likes, class_name: 'User', source: :liker
  has_many :comment_likes
```

**valuations/show**

```
<% @valuation.likers.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.name %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to like_valuation_path(:id => @valuation.id), class: "btn", method: :post do %>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up'></span> Like
<% end %>
```

**schema**

```
  create_table "valuation_likes", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "name"
    t.integer  "likes"
    t.integer  "valuation_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

  create_table "valuations", force: true do |t|
    t.boolean  "conceal",    default: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
    t.integer  "likes"
    t.text     "name"
  end

  add_index "valuations", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_valuations_on_user_id_and_created_at"
  add_index "valuations", ["user_id"], name: "index_valuations_on_user_id"
```

**Thank you!** Please let me know if you need anymore code, explanation, or visuals :)

Comment: In your controller I see `valuation_likes`.. but error I see `valuation_like`.. Note: **plural** form inside the controller..How it happened ?

Comment: Show the `user` model.

Comment: I think `User` model has missed the line `has_many :valuation_likes`.,, Pls check the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in `User` model, you don't have the line `has_many :valuation_likes`.  Add it, and it will work

Answer (score 1):

You may consider checking about [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), and making a 'likeable' class for reusability down the line.

Comment: Thanks @chad for the suggestion that's what I'm going to work on now :)

Answer (score 1):

As Arup says, you don't have a "has_many" relationship in your user model.

Alternatively, you can do...

```
@valuation_like = @valuation.valuation_likes.build(user: current_user)
```